# Does Java guarantee the member variable to be initialized to null by default?

Tags: java, initialization

```
class A {
    String mStr;
    A() {
        if (mStr == null) {
            // Does Java guarantee the execution will ALWAYS come here?
        }
    }
}
```

My question is embedded in the code above.

Comment: Could you refer me to the page of the Java specification?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3

Comment: Thank you very much, @Eashi